# How to add javascript code to google functions

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I want to write a google cloud function that will respond to POST requests. I want to write it in Javascript.

I've found Google's tutorial on how to do it, but at the beginning of the tutorial it says that this is a deprecated thing, and I have to do it using `Cloud Endpoints Frameworks for App Engine`. However, the link they provide doesn't help.

Any ideas on how to write a javascript google cloud function?

Link to the tutorial that I've found:
https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/legacy/v1/python/getstarted/clients/js/add_javascript

The warning that's displayed at the beginning of the tutorial:

> Cloud Endpoints Frameworks v1 has been deprecated and will be shut
>   down on August 2, 2018. We recommend that you use the latest version
>   of this feature, which is renamed to Cloud Endpoints Frameworks for
>   App Engine. This new version supports App Engine standard environment,
>   provides lower latency, and has better integration with App Engine.
>   For more details, see Migrating to 2.0.

The migration link points to https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/legacy/v1/python/migrating

Answer (score 1):

There are two completely different things you're talking about here.

[Google Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/) is a serverless way to write functions in Javascript which respond to HTTP requests.

[Google Cloud Endpoints Frameworks for App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/about-cloud-endpoints-frameworks) is a way to write App Engine applications in Python or Java which respond to HTTP requests.

The first link you provide is about writing browser-side JavaScript code which calls an Endpoints service. The corresponding link for the Endpoints 2.0 product is [here](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/consume_js).

Depending on what you actually want to do, you should consult one or more of these links.